# Problemas con subir aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio

Cuando deseo subir mi APK me muestra este error ya a esta le he quitado el debugger pero aún así me marca este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Tus archivos APK de aplicación instantánea deben incluir al menos un
>   APK base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para subir una aplicación ve a `Release management` > `App releases`.

Si vas a subir a producción directamente y no deseas realizar `Alpha` o `Beta Testing` ve a `MANAGE PRODUCTION` > `CREATE RELEASE`, da click en `BROWSE FILES` y agrega el archivo .APK de tu aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si estas realizando una `Instant App` tienes que obtener el base .apk y el .apk de tu instant app, agregarlos a un archivo .zip y este subirlo.

---

Con respecto al mensaje

> "Your Instant App APKs do not declare at least one web 'intent-filter'
>   element with the attribute 'android:autoVerify' set to true in the
>   Android Manifest."

Tienes que definir el intent filter:  `<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">` para que se pueda acceder a tu aplicación mediante el browser, por ejemplo

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
      <data android:host="example.com" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
      android:name="default-url"
      android:value="https://www.example.com/index.html" />
</activity>
```

Comment: Fijate que ahora me muestra esto: "You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:" pero volvi a generar el APK con la misma key singature pero aún así no me deja hacer esto. ¿No se si te ha pasado esto?

Comment: Ahora me muestra "Your Instant App APKs do not declare at least one web 'intent-filter' element with the attribute 'android:autoVerify' set to true in the Android Manifest." Tengo dos claves diferentes. ¿Puedo restaruar esto o hacer algo al respecto?

Comment: En tu aplicación cual es la Activity Launcher?, debes agrega el intent-filter:  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true"> revisa mi actualización. A que te refieres con 2 claves diferentes? dos keystores?

Comment: Si en efecto, la verificación en el manifest esta bien pero la kestore me marca como duplicada.